# try-catch returns variable as undefined

Tags: javascript, try-catch

Assuming both tries fail, **url** returns as undefined and console.log doesn't execute in this case. Is there a problem with my stacking of try-catch clauses, or with the scope of the url variable?

I am using try-catch because in my context url1,2, default may not be available.

```
getURL = function()
{
   var url;
      try{
        url=data.url1;
      }
      catch(err1)
      {
        try{
          url=data.url2;
        }
        catch(err2)
        {
          console.log("Fetching default url");
          url=data.defaulturl;
        }
      }
      finally
      {
        //do something with url
      }
}
```

I tried using an if-else-if structure, but it returns error if **data.url 1/2/default** is unavailable.

```
if('String' === typeof data.url1)
{
}
else if(check for url 2/default etc.){...}
```

Comment: If there's no `url` or `url2` attribute in the `data` object an assignment won't throw an exception, thus you code does not work as expected. Using try/catch in your case is also very hard to read. You should stick to testing the values of the data object (and the dataobject itself - if `data` is undefined, `data.url` will throw indeed).

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you do with `backurl`, where does `data` come from and might `data` be undefined too (probably)?

Comment: Might sound silly, but you forgot to `return` anything, so the function will always return undefined. To have it return the value of `url` you need, well, to have such line: `return url;".

Comment: Also, in the second catch, you assign the value to different variable, "backurl" so even if you return `url`, you won't return the proper value.

Comment: What is the purpose of getURL function? To check the presence of some properties in particular order and return the first matched? Or there would be some loading code? What is the `backurl` purpose?

Comment: Sorry, corrected the backurl issue. In my particular context data is the information fetched from a JSON file, but it's the same as with an object.

Comment: @dannychris37 My answer should fit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My last attempt to reinvent the question... But if all the keys are undefined or URL loadings are unsuccessful, there are NO success at all.

```
getURL = function() {
  var localData = data || {};
  var keys = ['url1', 'url2', 'defaulturl'];
  var success = false;
  var currentKey;
  while (!success && keys.length > 0) {
    currentKey = keys.shift();
    if (localData.hasOwnProperty(currentKey)
      && 'string' === typeof localData[currentKey]) {
      try {
        url = localData[currentKey];

        // Url loading code may throws an exception,
        // or you can throw it below by hands if needed

        // Emulate loading result...
        if (Math.random() > .5) {
          throw 'Error in ' + localData[currentKey] + ' loading';
        }

        success = true;
      } catch(exception) {
        // Logging or something else here
        console.log(exception.toString());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using try catch because some url's might not be available (data.urlx may be undefined) or some other URL-related errors might occur.  I will add what I mentioned in the question. If I want to check something, then I want to check whether data.urlx is a string (or not undefined). "data" is always an object.

Comment: My answer has been changed.

Comment: As for me, the `defaulturl` should not be separated from other keys, but owner better knows his ecosystem.

Comment: `!(currentKey = keys.shift())` returns true when there no more elements in keys to be removed? Did you write `!!` on purpose?

Comment: Your answer helped me solve my problem by using .hasOwnProperty instead of try-cath statements. Thanks!

Comment: @dannychris37, double ! may be used to get clear boolean value with same logic, but there is a bad case. NetBeans IDE marks assignments within if/whileconditions as warnings, so double negation converts assignment to ordinary boolean operand and remove warning also. There is a common pitfall in pop, shiftor other methods returning array items. An empty element (null, empty string (array, object), false, 0, etc) affects the end of loop or breaks if condition. I've rewrote my answer correctly.